# Discord.py - Is there a way to not delay other commands while uploading an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command where it sends a picture and since I don't have a really good internet connection, image upload takes a couple of seconds. I noticed that other commands are delayed and won't execute until the upload is finished. Is there a way to not delay other commands while sending an image?

I'm using `await ctx.send(file=file)`

Using hosting services is the last resort if there's no work arounds.

Edit: This is the async function that delay other commands.

```
    async def gacha(self, ctx, amount_of_pulls:int = 1):
        if amount_of_pulls > 10:
            await ctx.send(embed = embedder(ctx.author.avatar_url, " Uh oh! ", "The maximum of pulls you can do is `10`."))
            return

        sr = 0
        r = 0
        c = 0
        character_rarity = []

        for i in range(amount_of_pulls):
            if amount_of_pulls == 10 and i == 9:
                char = self.rate_gen(True)
                if char == "sr":
                    sr += 1
                    character_rarity.append("sr")
                elif char == "r":
                    r += 1
                    character_rarity.append("r")
                break

            char = self.rate_gen()
            if char == "sr":
                sr += 1
                character_rarity.append("sr")
            elif char == "r":
                r += 1
                character_rarity.append("r")
            elif char == "c":
                c += 1
                character_rarity.append("c")
        sr_count = sr if sr != 0 else "<:PepeKMS:821727726150615081>"
        r_count = r if r != 0 else "<:PepeKMS:821727726150615081>"

        pic_path = self.generate_image(character_rarity, len(character_rarity))
        with open(pic_path, "rb") as f:
            pic = File(f)
            await ctx.send(file = pic) 
        await ctx.send(embed = embedder(ctx.author.avatar_url, "☆☆★Gacha!★☆☆", f"You got:\n★★★: {sr_count}\n★★: {r_count}\n★: {c}"))
        os.remove(pic_path)
```

It takes a list of rarity from this function.

```
# Generates the rarity of the character
    def rate_gen(self, tenth_pull=False):
        y = randint(1, self.pool)
        if tenth_pull == True:
            if y >= 1 and y <= self.pool * self.sr_rate:
                return "sr"
            elif y >= (self.pool * self.sr_rate) + 1 and y <= self.pool:
                return "r"

        else:
            if y >= 1 and y <= self.pool * self.sr_rate:
                return "sr"
            elif y >= (self.pool * self.sr_rate) + 1 and y <= self.pool * self.r_rate:
                return "r"
            elif y >= (self.pool * self.r_rate) + 1 and y <= self.pool:
                return "c"
```

And then generates an image based on the list generated by the function above.

```
# Generates the image
    def generate_image(self, rarity, pull_amount):
        bg = Image.open("./data/priconne/images/gacha_bg.jpg")
        icon_border = Image.open("./data/priconne/images/icon_border.png")
        width, height = bg.size
        gacha_pull = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height))
        gacha_pull.paste(bg, (0, 0))
        char_pos_x = 338
        char_pos_y = 145
        tries = 0

        for r in range(pull_amount):
            if rarity[tries] == "sr":
                tries += 1
                f = open("./data/priconne/data/3star.json", "r")
                sr_file = f.read()
                sr_list = json.loads(sr_file)
                sr = choice(sr_list)

                for images in glob("./data/priconne/images/3star/*.png"):
                    z = images.split("\\")[1][:-4]
                    if z == sr:
                        sr_image = Image.open(images)
                        icon_border = Image.open("./data/priconne/images/3_icon_border.png")
                        gacha_pull.paste(sr_image, (char_pos_x, char_pos_y), mask=sr_image)
                        gacha_pull.paste(icon_border, (char_pos_x-2, char_pos_y), mask=icon_border)

                        char_pos_x += 159
                        if tries == 5:
                            char_pos_x = 338
                            char_pos_y += 170

                    else:
                        pass
                
            elif rarity[tries] == "r":
                    tries += 1
                    f = open("./data/priconne/data/2star.json", "r")
                    r_file = f.read()
                    r_list = json.loads(r_file)
                    r = choice(r_list)

                    for images in glob("./data/priconne/images/2star/*.png"):
                        z = images.split("\\")[1][:-4]
                        if z == r:
                            r_image = Image.open(images)
                            icon_border = Image.open("./data/priconne/images/2_icon_border.png")
                            gacha_pull.paste(r_image, (char_pos_x, char_pos_y), mask=r_image)
                            gacha_pull.paste(icon_border, (char_pos_x-2, char_pos_y), mask=icon_border)

                            char_pos_x += 159
                            if tries == 5:
                                char_pos_x = 338
                                char_pos_y += 170

                        else:
                            pass
            elif rarity[tries] == "c":
                    tries += 1
                    f = open("./data/priconne/data/1star.json", "r")
                    c_file = f.read()
                    c_list = json.loads(c_file)
                    c = choice(c_list)

                    for images in glob("./data/priconne/images/1star/*.png"):
                        z = images.split("\\")[1][:-4]
                        if z == c:
                            c_image = Image.open(images)
                            icon_border = Image.open("./data/priconne/images/1_icon_border.png")
                            gacha_pull.paste(c_image, (char_pos_x, char_pos_y), mask=c_image)
                            gacha_pull.paste(icon_border, (char_pos_x-2, char_pos_y), mask=icon_border)

                            char_pos_x += 159
                            if tries == 5:
                                char_pos_x = 338
                                char_pos_y += 170

                        else:
                            pass
        gacha_pull.save("./data/priconne/images/pull.png", optimize = True, quality = 95)
        return "./data/priconne/images/pull.png"
```

I notice that it always wait for the image to send first before doing other awaits and other commands.

I followed @SuperStormer's advice and it worked. Thank you!

```
@command(name="pull", aliases=["roll"])
    async def gacha(self, ctx, amount_of_pulls:int = 1):
        if amount_of_pulls > 10:
            await ctx.send(embed = embedder(ctx.author.avatar_url, " Uh oh! ", "The maximum of pulls you can do is `10`."))
            return

        sr = 0
        r = 0
        c = 0
        character_rarity = []

        for i in range(amount_of_pulls):
            if amount_of_pulls == 10 and i == 9:
                char = self.rate_gen(True)
                if char == "sr":
                    sr += 1
                    character_rarity.append("sr")
                elif char == "r":
                    r += 1
                    character_rarity.append("r")
                break

            char = self.rate_gen()
            if char == "sr":
                sr += 1
                character_rarity.append("sr")
            elif char == "r":
                r += 1
                character_rarity.append("r")
            elif char == "c":
                c += 1
                character_rarity.append("c")
        sr_count = sr if sr != 0 else "<:PepeKMS:821727726150615081>"
        r_count = r if r != 0 else "<:PepeKMS:821727726150615081>"

        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        pic_path = await loop.run_in_executor(pool(), self.generate_image, character_rarity, len(character_rarity))

        with open(pic_path, "rb") as f:
            pic = File(f)
            await ctx.send(file = pic) 
        await ctx.send(embed = embedder(ctx.author.avatar_url, "☆☆★Gacha!★☆☆", f"You got:\n★★★: {sr_count}\n★★: {r_count}\n★: {c}"))
        os.remove(pic_path)
```

Turns out that the *args and **kwargs are seperated from the function itself.

Comment: You are using async function which is supposed to work parallel to other functions, there should be no delay this way. Maybe post full functions so we can see if there is something that is causing the delay.

Comment: @BijayRegmi I have edited my post to show the function I made.

Comment: `generate_image` is sync code that is blocking the entire thread. Check out `asyncio.run_in_executor` to run it in a separate thread.

Comment: @SuperStormer I've tried reading around and I'm having a hard time understanding how `run_in_executor` works. I'll edit my post to show what I did. If you don't mind can you please push me in the right direction?

Comment: After searching around more, I finally figured it out. Thank you so much @SuperStormer! It didn't cross my mind the the thing that's delaying it is the `generate_image`. I've tested it before and thought that because it generate the image almost instantaneously, it shouldn't have been delaying it. Again Thank you!